# Web scraping Wunderground

Tags: r

in the last couple of month I used a code to get historical data from Wunderground. The code worked. But since today they somehow changed the website. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with html stuff. This was the code which worked:

```
webpage <- read_html("https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/LOWW/date/2018-06?dayend=18&monthend=6&yearend=2018&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=")

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

weather.data <- html_table(tbls)[[2]]
```

This code selected the second table on the website. Does anyone has an idea why it does not work anymore? They somehow changed the description for the nodes?

Cheers

Comment: Why are you not using the api? there are 2 packages, rwunderground and wunderscraper that use the api.

Comment: Because the API does only allow a certain amount of requested data per day. As far as I know...